# ReferenceError: Rx is not defined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am just started learning angular2 and I am trying to do sample of RxJs using angular2. It would be highly appreciated, If some one help me.

RxJs Code-

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
       .take(5)
       .do(i => console.log(i) );
```

package.json

```
  {
    "name": "angular-quickstart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
      "lite": "lite-server",
      "postinstall": "typings install",
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
      "typings": "typings"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
      "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
      "typescript": "^2.0.3",
      "typings":"^1.4.0"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you import 'rxjs' ?

Comment: @ti2005 thnx for response, Yes I have imported rxjs

Comment: I was trying to visit mixer.com and I got the error message: `Something is very wrong... Please contact us with the following error:
ReferenceError: rxjs is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the Rx before Observable-

```
var obs = Observable.interval(500)
   .take(5)
   .do(i => console.log(i) );
```

Answer (score 10):

**Update 2020:**

For those using the CDN listed on their readme, i.e. `https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js`.

The developers must have changed the global namespace for rxjs  from `Rx` to `rxjs`, so use `rxjs` instead of `Rx`,

```
var obs = rxjs.Observable.interval(500)
       .take(5)
       .do(i => console.log(i) );
```

For more information, read the [rxjs's README.md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs?ml_subscriber=1391315501082219548&ml_subscriber_hash=i9s6&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=learn_rxjs_v6_now_subjects_testing_marbles_operators_advanced_uses_more&utm_term=2020-04-03)

Comment: When I use https://unpkg.com/browse/rxjs@7.3.0/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js at JsFiddle I know get 'rxjs' undefined.I could fix this with directly point to the script via html script tag:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.3.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

1. npm install rxjs

*counter.ts*

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

// To get the typescript compiler to recognise Rx.* execute.
// npm install @types/rx --save-dev

let obs = Observable.interval(1000);


obs.subscribe(value => console.log("Subscriber: " + value));
```

2. tsc counter.ts
3. node counter.js

   Subscriber: 0

   Subscriber: 1

   Subscriber: 2

^C