# Uncaught ReferenceError: Rx is not defined

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This my code HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This my code Js file

```
const stream = Rx.Observable.create(...);
```

When I want to use Rx I get Error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Rx is not defined

I can’t understand what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: Rx is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806285/referenceerror-rx-is-not-defined)

Comment: The answer from `ReferenceError: Rx is not defined` does not work for me.

Comment: Which version of RxJS did you install

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.5.3"

Comment: Probably a better duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461723/import-umd-javascript-modules-into-browser. Adrian’s answer is good, the UMD module was renamed from `Rx` to `rxjs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RxJs 6 the object is called rxjs

```
const stream = rxjs.Observable.create(...);
```

or

```
const { Observable } = rxjs;
const stream = Observable.create(...);
```

If you are using npm then you need to import the parts you need as the main thing about RxJs 6 over 5 is that it is tree shakeable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const stream = Observable.create(...);
```

Comment: now I get the error Test.js: 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: If you are including the full package rxjs.umd.min.js then use one of the first two methods, the import method is if you are using a build system like webpack.